# Inverse Fourier transform in 3D with q^n in denominator

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Mathematician guys, Could you help me to find below integral?

$$\int_{- \infty}^ {\infty} \frac{\exp(-i k.r) f(k)}{k^4} d^3k$$

I know below definition:

$$\int_{- \infty}^ {\infty} \exp(-i k.r) f(k) d^3k = F(r)$$

I need both cases: 1- f(r) is spherically symmetric 2_ It is symmetric just in x and y-direction. Any answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: To the editor: in the future, refrain from adding statement like the last one you added. It is not needed and can change intent.

Comment: Do you know anything more about the behaviour of $f(k)$ or $F(r)$? Furthermore, are $k$ and $r$ vectors?

Comment: Do you know contour integration?

Comment: k and r are both vectors in 3D space. @NDewolf

Comment: I know a little about that. Is it solvable by contour integration in 3d? I have no idea how to solve it @Paul

Comment: Often these integrals are either separable, or $f$ is isometric, so you can take advantage of spherical symmetry.  There are a lot of techniques for evaluating these, since integrals of this form are ubiquitous in the solving of problems with Feynman diagrams.

Comment: Which information about F could help to find the integral? @Paul

Comment: Whether it's spherically symmetric or separable in terms of $k_x,k_y,k_z$.

Comment: I need both cases:1- it is spherically symmetric 2_ It is symmetric just in x and y-axis. Is it enough? @Paul

Comment: As a spherically symmetric function it is simple to reduce the problem to a single variable integral by integrating out the angles, and the resulting integral can be done by contour integration.  For the second case, I'd have to see the specifics to be sure.

Comment: Where can I find the contour integration for this problem? @Paul

Comment: 1) Use the convolution theorem
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\frac{f(k)}{k^{4}}e^{-ik\cdot{r}}d^{(3)}k=\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\frac{e^{-ik\cdot{r}}}{k^{4}}d^{(3)}k\Big)*F(r)=\Big(\frac{sign(r)}{6}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}r^{3}\Big)*F(r)$$
2)If
$$G(r)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\frac{f(k)e^{-ik\cdot{r}}}{k^{4}}d^{(3)}\vec{k}$$
Then
$$\nabla^{2}\nabla^{2}G(r)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}f(k)e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot{\vec{r}}}d^{(3)}\vec{k}=F(r)$$
So
$$\nabla^{2}\nabla^{2}G(r)=F(r)$$
Then you might want to find the Green's function of the biharmonic operator with the desired symmetry properties.

Comment: Why did you use sign function? Could r be negative?! @KirylPesotski