# Green's function of the biharmonic operator with symmetry n one direction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

This question is somehow related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313871/inverse-fourier-transform-in-3d-with-qn-in-denominator?noredirect=1#comment4763814_2313871).
Knowing that $F(r)$ has symmetry respect to x and y-direction in Cartesian coordinate, Could any one find $G(r)$ from below equation?

$$\nabla^2 \nabla^2 G(r) = F(r)$$

Answer (score 0):

As you have the symmetry in the $x-y$ plane, you might want to use the cylindrical coordinates. In those coordinates, $F$ is independent of angles due to the symmetry property. Now let $\nabla^{2}G=S$. Then
$$\nabla^{2}S=F(\rho, z)$$
Or, using the Green's function method you have
$$S(\rho,\varphi, z)=\int\mathcal{G}(\rho, \varphi, z, \rho', \varphi', z')F(\rho', z')d\rho'd\varphi'dz'$$
Where
$$\nabla^{2}\mathcal{G}=\delta(\rho-\rho')\delta(z-z')\delta(\varphi-\varphi')$$
Then you also have
$$\nabla^{2}G=S$$
I.e.
$$G(\rho,\varphi, z)=\int\mathcal{G}(\rho, \varphi, z, \rho'', \varphi'', z'')S(\rho'', z'')d\rho''d\varphi''dz''$$
This is
$$G(\rho,\varphi, z)=\int\int\mathcal{G}(\rho, \varphi, z, \rho'', \varphi'', z'')\mathcal{G}(\rho'', \varphi'', z, \rho', \varphi', z')F(\rho', \varphi'){d\rho'd\varphi'dz'}{d\rho''d\varphi''dz''}$$
The Green's function is known to be
$$\mathcal{G}(\rho, \varphi, z, \rho', \varphi', z')=\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}}I_{m}(k\rho)K_{m}(k\rho')e^{im(\varphi-\varphi')}\cos(k(z-z'))dk$$